# How often are Chainlink price feeds updated?

Tags: oracles, chainlink

I browsed through the [Chainlink docs](https://docs.chain.link/) but I couldn't find an answer for how often prices are updated.

My understanding is that they have a rule that if the markets become super volatile, they immediately post an update to the data feeds. But normally prices are updated once every so often (1 hour?).

Could someone familiar with Chainlink answer this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are currently 2 "trigger" parameters that kick off Chainlink nodes to update.

### 1. A deviation parameter

The Chainlink nodes are monitoring the prices of the assets off-chain. If the real-world price of an asset deviates past some interval, it will trigger all the nodes to do an update. Right now, most Ethereum data feeds have a 0.5% deviation threshold.

### 2. A time interval

If the price stays within the deviation parameters, it will only trigger an update every X minutes / hours.

You can see these parameters on [data.chain.link](https://data.chain.link/ethereum/mainnet/crypto-usd/eth-usd) on an example like ETH / USD.

Comment: On another note, thanks for bringing up that this should be in the docs!

Comment: Where can one find this deviation parameter on-chain?